# Tell PHP to use MAMP PHP Binary

Tags: php, macos, mamp, passthru

I am on Mac osx, using MAMP server. I am working on a php project that has a php script with a line similar to the following:

```
passthru("php path/to/script.php");
```

This was causing some serious issues which I was able to rectify by hard-coding the path to my MAMP php binary ie.

```
passthru("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/bin/php path/to/script.php");
```

Obviously this is a hack fix, not a solution. Is there a way I can tell php/apache to use the MAMP php binary when executing exec() or passthru() commands?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `include` the PHP script?